# Firebase cloud functions work locally but not after deployment

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently attempting to deploy a Nuxt SSR app to Firebase.

Everything works correctly on local and the firebase server. The cloud function correctly executes and renders the html, no problem.

The problem happens when I add a request to and external API (Storyblok). I'm on the Blaze plan so external requests should work, right?

Everything works on local using the cloud functions emulator and through `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` with the external API request but I get an error 500 after deploying.

Is there a way to get a more detailed log of what may be happening on the Firbase end?

Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const config = {
  dev: false,
  buildDir: 'nuxt',
  build: {
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  }
}
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=150, s-maxage=150');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nuxt.render(req, res, promise => {
      promise.then(resolve).catch(reject)
    })
  });
}

app.use(handleRequest);
exports.nuxtssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `debug: true` in your Nuxt config.

i.e.

```
const config = {
  debug: true,
  dev: false,
  buildDir: 'nuxt',
  build: {
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  }
}
```

This will make the error message shows in browser, instead of just error 500.

Answer (score -2):

Referring you to :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#viewing_logs

perhaps this would have more details using Using the Firebase CLI.